# Criteria method for nhibernate

Tags: c#, asp.net, hibernate, nhibernate, criteria

Is there a way to give method a Criteria and then run it from code?
For example

```
    public static List<T> ToList(ICriteria criteria)
    {
        ISession session = NhSessionHelper.GetCurrentSession();
        List<T> l = session.+criteria;
        return l;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can you DetachedCriteria for it:

```
public static List<T> ToList(DetachedCriteria criteria)
{
    ISession session = NhSessionHelper.GetCurrentSession();
    List<T> l = criteria.GetExecutableCriteria(session).List<T>();
    return l;
}
```